# How to add and select an element in html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a row and I want to send data to another page, while click on the "add" button. Then I want to remove the "add" class and add the "remove" class and again if I click on "remove" remove it and add "add" class.
My code is below but it doesn't work properly

```
$(function() {
  //selecting a class that contains "btn" and "add" class
  $('.btn.add').click(function() {
    $(this).text("remove");
    $(this).addClass("remove");
    $(this).removeClass("add");
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),
      $name = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)"),
      $id = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'feed.php',
      data: {
        meal: $name.text(),
        day: $id.text()
      },
      success: function(msg) {
        $row.css({
          'background-color': 'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.3)'
        });
      }
    });
  });
  //selecting a class that contains "btn" and "add" class
  $('.btn.remove').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("remove");
    $(this).addClass("remove");
    $(this).text("add");
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),
      $name = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)"),
      $id = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)");
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'feed.php',
      data: {
        meal: $name.text(),
        day: $id.text()
      },
      success: function(msg) {
        $('#note').html(msg.aaa + ' ' + msg.bbb + ' ' + msg.ccc);
        $row.css({
          'background-color': 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3'
        });
      }
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: *"It doesn't work properly"* is a meaningless problem description by itself without any other debugging information. Please help us help you by taking a few minutes to read [ask] then edit the question with properly detailed problem description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was unable to understand your main problem but your code can be minified as below, there is no need to repeat your code again only for the reason of class.

```
 $('.btn').click(function(){
    // to change the text
    if($(this).text().trim() === 'add') {
        $(this).text('remove')
    } else {
        $(this).text('add')
    }

    // to change the class name
    if($(this).hasClass('add')) {
        $(this).addClass('remove').removeClass('add')
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('add').removeClass('remove')
    }
    // further code here conditionally
});
```